# Import CSV to Excel (variable width data) causing #REF problem

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel workbook that takes the raw data on a sheet "rawData" and does a whole heap of useful things. I have added a Master sheet for users to go to and click a button to import a new data set; replace the contents of "rawData" and have the whole workbook auto update. Including graphs and other things. I've recorded sections of macro and replaced a few things to get it to kind of work. But there are a few problems I just cannot solve.

See code.

One problem is if I delete the rawData sheet, all the refereneces break, even if I subsequently recreate it. If I delete the contents of the sheet, that also breaks the references, giving me #REF propogating through the rest of the workbook.

Next problem is that I recorded the import CSV macro based on one data set. But ultimately, the user's data set may contain hundreds of columns. The recorded macro always has hard coded ranges in it. How do I generalise it to accomodate any CSV width?

The imported data appears as a table. When I step through, I can't paste the new data over this. the error is:

> Cannot complete operation: A Table cannot overlpa with a pivotTable
>   report, query results. a table , merged cells or an XML mapping.

I don't know how to just import the data as text. I don't really understand what the table is about. But clearly it's preventing me from overwirting the contents of the cells. Is there a way to import without formatting the data as a table?

```
Sub openReportAndFormat()
'
' openReportAndFormat Macro
'




' Kill all existing queries onthis workbook.
 '   While ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count
 '       ActiveWorkbook.Queries(1).Delete
 '   Wend


 On Error GoTo Oops




' Open your file.
   ' myReport = "C:\Users\thebi\Downloads\sn_billing.csv"
    myReport = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.csv", , "Browse for Your Billing Report")
    'MsgBox myReport

  '  Dim wb As Workbook
  '  Dim ws As Worksheet
  '  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  '  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

' Open the file & format it.
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="billingQuery", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & myReport & """),[Delimiter="","", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", Int64.Type}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=billingQuery;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [billingQuery]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
     '   .ListObject.DisplayName = "Billing"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With



    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("billingQuery").Delete

    On Error GoTo forgotToDeleteError
' Put in temp and copy all.
' Delete everything in rawData.
' Paste in everything to A1. Format as table.
' delete temp.
    ActiveSheet.Name = "temp"
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("rawData").Select
    Columns("A:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("temp").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete


    Exit Sub


Oops:
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("billingQuery").Delete
    MsgBox "A Previous File Grab Crashed and messed up your query. Try again!"


forgotToDeleteError:
   ' Worksheets("rawData").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Name = "rawData"
End Sub
```

Ideally, I want to import a CSV file of any width, and have it overwrite the contents of "rawData" sheet, without any forward references breaking. And the query cleaned up so it can run again. Also basic error checking so it doesn't get into a muddle and break all the references... I'm compete VBA newcomer, so it's all been guess work getting to this point! Exert help please!

Comment: I'm interested to know 2 things 1) if you have a CSV of unknown width, how do you know the order and data type when adding the query? 2) same principle as 1, how does your 'whole heap of useful things' know which column to use?

Comment: The data structure is predictable, but contains an unknown number of records. Each record containing 2 columns worth of data side by side. So I figure out which columns are useful based on =IFERROR() and IF(<>"", ...) sort of checks. Then perform conditional column hide. And exclude hidden columns from graphs... That sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

With access to the CSV generation, here's one thing you can do. Figure out the maximum width and create one row that's that length full of empty data. That way you always get a known width. Problem one solved (badly nut nonetheless).

Then in the code, don't try to copy and paste the entire table: But do this:

```
Sub clearCopyPaste()
'
' clearCopyPaste Macro
'


' Set up sheets
    ActiveSheet.Name = "temp"
    Dim temp As Worksheet, rawData As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
    Set temp = Sheets("temp")
    Set rawData = Sheets("rawData")

' clear data from rawData.
    Sheets("rawData").Select
    lr = temp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Rows("2:" & lr).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

' copy data & paste from temp!
    Sheets("temp").Select
    lr = temp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows("2:" & lr).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("rawData").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

That should mean you don't have any junk hanging around below the active range either since you clean it up before loading a new CSV source file.

Open to better answers.